# Python - how to find the position of the second lowest value in a list

Tags: python, list

I have the following list:

```
list = [7,3,6,4,6]
```

I know I can use `list.index(min(list))` to find the position of the lowest number in the list, but how do I use it to find the **second** lowest?

Comment: it's a little more complicated than the dupe proposal. For instance, using `heapq` doesn't qualify here, because you have to associate the index, not only the value.

Comment: I don't even understand, what "second lowest value" in a context like `alist = [7, 3, 6, 4, 6, 3]` means. Is the expected output the second three or the four?

Comment: It's _not_ a duplicate. However not reopening, because it got enough answers :)

Comment: @Piinthesky not sure OP thought about that (or gives a damn).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

don't use list as a var name

edit, originally misread as index of 2nd highest - fixed now, thanx Jean-François Fabre

```
lst = [7,3,6,4,6]

lst.index(sorted(lst)[1])

Out[161]: 3

lst[3]
Out[162]: 4

sorted(lst)
Out[163]: [3, 4, 6, 6, 7]
```

the above has a problem with repeated numbers in the input list, by using `.index` you get the index of the 1st match

```
lst = [1, 1, 7,3,6,4,6]

lst.index(sorted(lst)[1])
Out[9]: 0                  # 0 is wrong, the postion of the 2nd smallest is 1
```

I think this fixes it

```
n = 1
sorted([*enumerate(lst)], key=lambda x: x[1])[n][0]
Out[11]: 1
```

looking at the pieces

```
[*enumerate(lst)]
Out[12]: [(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 7), (3, 3), (4, 6), (5, 4), (6, 6)]
```

`enumerate` pairs a count with the values in the input `lst`, `*` forces 'unpacking' of the enumerate object, the outer sq brackets 'catch' this output in a `list`

inside Python builtin `sorted` the 2nd argument `key=lambda x: x[1]` tell it to look in the 2nd position of the tuples from `[*enumerate(lst)]` which are the numbers from `lst`

```
sorted([*enumerate(lst)], key=lambda x: x[1])
Out[13]: [(0, 1), (1, 1), (3, 3), (5, 4), (4, 6), (6, 6), (2, 7)]
```

the indexing that list with `[n][0]` gets the n-th sorted tuple, and takes the 1st value from the tuple which is the index asigned in `enumerate`

Comment: That's returned the number 2 - what does this mean?

Comment: answer is incorrect -2 should be 1 to pick the second lowest, not highest.

Comment: mis read, yes, index sorted by 1 for 2nd lowest, fixed

Comment: @f5r5e5d just out of interest, if I put other numbers in the square brackets at the end, what would they do? For example how would I find the 3rd lowest value?

Answer (score 1):

you could sort the `enumerate`d list according to value, and pick the second item.

```
def second_pos(numbers):
    return sorted(enumerate(numbers),key=lambda x:x[::-1])[1][0]

print(second_pos([7,3,6,4,6]))
```

result: 3, as 4 is the second lowest value

This solution involves one `sort` operation only, no `index` operation afterwards to find the index, saving that last `O(n)` operation.

Note that there's a tiebreaker picking the lowest positionned item in case 2 values are equal.

Also note that if the list is too small, you can get an `IndexError`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
list.index(sorted(list)[1])
```

Comment: what does each part of this do?

Comment: Oops sorry: sorted just sort your list in ascending order. So you know that your  second lowest will be at the second position "1" in our case. that is why  i put the "sorted(list)[1]" toget its value. and then the list.index(value) will give you the index of an element in your list.  Sorry for the late answer guy!

Comment: This solution messes with the indexes you’re trying to retrieve. If you need the indexes intact from the original list, go with the selected answer.

Comment: @dmoz really? how? sorted is not like sort.

Comment: Because `sorted` creates a new list with new indexes, no? If that’s what you’re looking for, great, but if you need the original indexes, then the accepted answer might work better, right?

Comment: you only use it to get the element and then get the its index in the original list. Your original list does not change at all my friend.

Answer (score 1):

Use `set` to get rid of duplicates, like this

```
lowest_nth = 2
lst.index(sorted(set(lst))[lowest_nth-1])
```

Edit (important remark):

If you try with this code, will see a wrong result with duplicated values if `set` is not used:

```
lst = [7, 6, 6, 4, 3, 8]

def get_index_without_using_set():
    return lst.index(sorted(lst)[lowest_nth-1])

def get_index_using_set():
    return lst.index(sorted(set(lst))[lowest_nth-1])

print(lst)
print()
print('Without set:')
for lowest_nth in range(1,6):
    print('lowest {}: {}'.format(lowest_nth, get_index_without_using_set()))

print()
print('With set:')
for lowest_nth in range(1,6):
    print('lowest {}: {}'.format(lowest_nth, get_index_using_set()))


Output:

[7, 6, 6, 4, 3, 8]

Without set:
lowest 1: 4
lowest 2: 3
lowest 3: 1
lowest 4: 1  <-- wrong index, see below
lowest 5: 0

With set:
lowest 1: 4
lowest 2: 3
lowest 3: 1
lowest 4: 0
lowest 5: 5
```

Comment: but doesn't that destroy the indexes?

Comment: `set(lst)` makes a new object, doesn't touch the original `lst`. Indeed it destroys the indexes in that object, but `sorted` makes an ordered list again. I don't wont' the index yet, just the lowest nth value in the set. Then `lst.index` method gives the wanted index result for that value.

Comment: ok, I was right to comment with a ? in the end. that's right.

Comment: check my edit @Jean

Comment: it's because OP didn't define any strategy for equal values. Your answer is good.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove the min and then get the min of the new list that has a new min , which would be the second min. I made a copy of the list so it would work but probably don't need to do that.

```
lst_copy = list(lst)
lst.remove(min(lst))
    lst_copy.index(min(lst))
```

Comment: That doesn't work as written - `.remove()` modifies the list in place, and returns None.  The basic idea is valid, though.

Comment: `list(list)`: that's not going to work :)

Comment: I'm just using the list function -
 https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list and the variable is list.  Why would it not work.

Comment: Because python can't associate two things (the function and the variable) with the same name. This is why one shouldn't name things the same as built-ins. (I realize it's in the OP, but you should change it)

Comment: ok changed it to lst

Answer (score 0):

This seems appropriate:

```
def find_2nd_smallest(iterable):
    try:
        st = set(iterable)
        st.discard(min(st))
        return iterable.index(min(st))
    except:
        return None

my_list = [7,3,6,4,6]
print (find_2nd_smallest(my_list))
```

prints the index of the first occurrence of the 2nd smallest:

```
3
```

And if you want a function where you can input the number smallest (the `2` means 2nd smallest):

```
def find_nth_smallest(iterable,n):
    try:
        st = set(iterable)
        for i in range(n-1):
            st.discard(min(st))
        return iterable.index(min(st))
    except: return None

my_list = [7,3,6,4,6]
print (find_nth_smallest(my_list,2))
```

Please note these functions may not be the most efficient solutions.